# Anyone knows what exactly does jpackage do?

Tags: java

When doing some deployment, I saw java is sometimes coming with jpackage. what exactly does jpackage do, anyone knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPackage takes commonly used bits of Java technology and organizes them into the RPM package manager.

To do this, they basically write a lot of RPM spec files, and maintain them as the various software components (JUnit, javac, etc) change over time.  They also improve on the alignment of the Java software stack with other initiatives, like the Linux Standard Base.

When things go smoothly, the end result is that every library is in the "right" place, and that software components that require libraries don't ship with multiple copies (one JUnit for Netbeans, one JUnit for Eclipse, one JUnit for stand-alone), instead all software packages use the "system" JUnit libraries.  Doing so makes the package manager aware of the dependency complexity, and reduces the size of all the needed installable elements as a whole.

Comment: Now that JPackage has mostly met all of their goals, which was to get java sensibly managed through RPM packaging, many of the items that were previously only available through JPackage are now the base distros.  You should look to your base distro to see if the package you need is there, before adopting a JPackage RPM.